# UIView in greyscale. View not being redrawn

Tags: ios, uiview, grayscale

I managed to get a UIView in greyscale by adding the following view on top:

```
@interface GreyscaleAllView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *underlyingView;

@end

@implementation GreyscaleAllView

@synthesize underlyingView;

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // draw the image
    [self.underlyingView.layer renderInContext:context];

    // set the blend mode and draw rectangle on top of image
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeColor);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    [super drawRect:rect];
}

@end
```

It works, but the content doesn't get updated unless i manually call setNeedsDisplay. (I can press a UIButton and the action fires, but nothing changes in appearance) So for it to behave like expected I call setNeedsDisplay 60 times each second. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

The viewcontroller inits the overlayview with this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    GreyscaleAllView *grey = [[[GreyscaleAllView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame] autorelease];
    grey.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    grey.userInteractionEnabled = NO;    
    [self.view addSubview:grey];
}
```

I've added this for the underlaying views to redraw:

```
@implementation GreyscaleAllView

- (void)setup {

    self.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
    self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;

    [self redrawAfter:1.0 / 60.0 repeat:YES];

}

- (void)redrawAfter:(NSTimeInterval)time repeat:(BOOL)repeat {

    if(repeat) {
        // NOTE: retains self - should use a proxy when finished
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:time target:self selector:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: can you add the code from where you are initialising this gray scale view?

Comment: added viewcontroller initcode and redrawcode

Comment: try using GreyscaleAllView *grey = [[[GreyscaleAllView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)] autorelease];

Comment: that should and does not do any difference. (It's an iPad project so setting that frame leads to only a portion of the view beeing in greyscale)

Comment: As we using custom view, so we need to provide the frame, then u need to try with iPad dimension, just try it once and let me know if it works?

Comment: shure. Just did, and it's the same, but I can't see initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024) beeing any different than what I have (initWithFrame:self.view.frame) when self.view covers the whole screen

Comment: can you check the value of rect by putting nslog inside drawrect?

Comment: tried and its working for me, what do you mean by "It works, but the content doesn't get updated unless i manually call setNeedsDisplay. "

Comment: The timer triggering setNeedsDisplay needs to be active for the underlying views to be redrawn. Try putting some buttons or swithes or whatever on the view below the overlay and see what happens (or doesn't when we don't do setNeedsDisplay all the time)

Comment: are you adding new views on self.view or grayView?

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is for the subview to only be told to redraw when the parent view redraws, in which case you can override `-setNeedsDisplay` in the parent view and make it call `-setNeedsDisplay` on the `GreyscaleAllView`. This requires subclassing UIView for your `UIViewController`'s `view` property.

i.e. implement `loadView` in the controller, and set

```
self.view = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

where CustomView overrides `setNeedsDisplay` as described above:

```
@implementation CustomView

- (void)setNeedsDisplay
{
    [grayView setNeedsDisplay]; // grayView is a pointer to your GreyscaleAllView
    [super setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

For completeness, you should also do the same for `-setNeedsDisplayInRect:`